# Logical operators should be avoided (use || instead of 'or') sensiolabs insight

Tags: php, logical-operators

I'm using SensioLabs Insight to keep my projects code quality on top of the used tool's best practices.

This line cause warning during SLInsight analysis:

```
$handle = fopen($file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file: '.$file);
```

SensioLabs say :

> Logical operators should be avoided.
>
> [...]
>
> *The or operator does not have the same precedence as ||. This could lead to unexpected behavior, use || instead.*

Ok but, if I simply use || instead of 'or' , like this :

```
$handle = fopen($file, 'w') || die('Cannot open file: '.$file);
```

I get the classic `No such file or directory` erro because of `fopen` fail,
instead of what I'm expecting (die action and return message).

To avoid this, I use a condition before do the `fopen`:

```
if(!file_exists($file)) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Le fichier '.$file.' n\'existe pas.');
}
$handle = fopen($file'.log', 'r');
```

What is the good use of '||' in a variable assignment for what I want ?

Thank's by advance for enlighten me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Logical operators should be avoided.

In your case is the precedence of the `or` that you want. I think that SensioLabs refers to a complex expressions in a condition, which can be misleading.

`or` operator have lower precedence, even lower than assignment `=` operator. Example:

```
if ($a = getRecordOrFalse($userId) || $boolValue) {
```

is as you would expect:

```
if (($a = getRecordOrFalse($userId)) || ($boolValue)) {
```

`$a` contains the value returned `getRecordOrFalse`, and this condition is `true` if `$boolValue` is true, even if `$a` isn't. But with the `or` you get a completely different behavior:

```
if ($a = getRecordOrFalse($userId) or $boolValue) {
```

that's equivalent to:

```
if ($a = (getRecordOrFalse($userId) or $boolValue)) {
```

Now `$a` would be a boolean value given by the result of `getRecordOrFalse($userId) or $boolValue)`'s condition.

But in your case this make sense:

```
$handle = (fopen($file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file: '.$file));
```

What you can do to improve readability is to use a condition like this:

```
if (false === $handle = fopen($file, 'w')) {
    die('Cannot open file: '.$file);
}
```

Or simply

```
if (!$handle = fopen($file, 'w')) {
    die('Cannot open file: '.$file);
}
```